# FilePicker: How to pick an audio file based on users choice and play using a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8

I want the user to choose audio from their system. This audio should be played on click, is this possible. From all the give documents, you can only pick images. Please help for the same.

Comment: Look into [html5 audio elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File Picker API allows you to specify whatever file types you want. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465199.aspx and notice that you can just change fileTypeFilter to whatever file extensions you need (e.g. mp3, wma, etc.).

Once you get a StorageFile object for the chosen file, use URL.createObjectURL(, { oneTimeOnly : true}) and assign the result to an audio element's src attribute. That'll load it up and you can then instruct the audio element to play/pause/etc. as you need.

Scenario 4 of the [Playback Manager msAudioCategory sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Playback-Manager-e6526e67) (js/foregroundonlymedia.js) does exactly what you need. Scenario 1 shows background audio if you need that.

Comment: Thanks Kraig! Your answer is perfect!